# Elementar integral $\int e^xa^x \, dx$

Tags: integration

I can't use substitution or integration by parts.
$$\int e^xa^x \, dx$$
Solution is
$$ \frac {e^xa^x}{1+\ln(a)}+c $$
But why is there "$1$"
$$\int e^x = e^x + c$$
and
$$ \int a^x \, dx = \frac {a^x}{\ln(a)}+c $$
There is no "$1$" there.

Comment: Ln(ae) = lna + lne = 1 + lna

Comment: @Neymar Ou thank you very much.

Comment: $$e^xa^x=e^{x}e^{x\log(a)}=e^{(1+\log(a))x}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that $$e^xa^x=(ae)^x$$ and then integrate

Comment: I just don't understand how to convert it to that solution.
int (ae)^x  = (ae)x/ln(ae) + c.

Comment: It is $$\frac{(ea)^x}{ea}+C$$